# multiple ajax call and array variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I am running in to some interesting situation. on my application I have couple of situations.
1. I have to grab data from two different sources.(for that i have used ajax call).
2. I have to manipulate those data comparing to each other. if both are equal than third array will gets the value input from first array first array. and Eventually i have to return the third value and work on my graphs.

so for that I have :

```
 getData : function(){
    var bubbleArray= [];
    var companyData=[];
    var managerData =[];
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "data/companyData.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (bubbleJsonData){
     $.each (bubbleJsonData.main.DATA_RECORD, function(index, response){
          if(response.C_HRS!=0&&response.D_CUST_HRS!=0){
    companyData.push([(response.C_HRS/442)*100, (response.D_CUST_HRS/442)*100, ((response.D_CUST_HRS/response.C_HRS)*100), response.C_HRS, response.D_CUST_HRS, response.CPY_NAME ]);
            }
            });
        },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert("Error:"+ errorThrown);
            }
//ajax call to get the managerData. 
$.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "data/managerData.json",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(managerjsonData){
            $.each (managerjsonData.main.DATA _RECORD, function(index, responsedata){
            if(responsedata.CPY_NAME!=""){
            managerData.push([responseData.CPY_NAME]);
            }
            });
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("Error:"+ errorThrown);
            }

             });

    });
```

now, I have to compare the managerData. CPY_NAME with companyData.CPY_NAME if the match found generate the bubbleArray with the details of companyData means bubbleArray should have C_HRS, D_CUST_HRS,..........
if any help available form anybody would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until both the requests finish and save their results in some variable, and then compare them.

```
var yourAjaxRequests = [];
var jqXHR = $.ajax();
yourAjaxRequests.push(jqXHR);

$.when.apply($, yourAjaxRequests).done(function() {
    /* compare logic here */
);
```

Comment: yeah I had a feeling about that..... but I don't know how would i put this above code in my application.